# How to compare Date from DateTime in CosmosDb using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I need to compare only Date from the DateTime using LINQ in CosmosDb. But this is not working. Following is my code sample:

In .Where(x => x.Date.Date == date.Date) this is not evaluated properly as I guess. I also found some previous article where it mentioned that DateTime is not supported by CosmosDb in the LINQ. Is it still the case? Or, are there some other possibilities?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Milking>> hasAlreadyExistsForThisDate(DateTime date)
 {
     var query = _milkingContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<Milking>()
         .Where(x => x.Date.Date == date.Date)
         .ToFeedIterator();

     var milkings = new List<Milking>();

     while (query.HasMoreResults)
     {
         var response = await query.ReadNextAsync();
         milkings.AddRange(response);
     }

     return milkings;

 }
```

Database (Azure CosmosDb):

```
{
    "id": "7e7614ed-d9df-45db-aaee-5586e05dc300",
    "date": "2023-12-26T18:33:57.703Z",
    "pegs": [
        125,
        120,
        80
    ],
    "_rid": "rn5YAIalsYoMAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/rn5YAA==/colls/rn5YAIalsYo=/docs/rn5YAIalsYoMAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-382a-2a71928201da\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1703615671
}
```

Comment: "not working" is not a description of a problem. What actually happens? That's not something we should have to ask.

Comment: Description updated @jmcilhinney

Comment: CosmosDB [doesn't have a DateTime type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/working-with-dates) and dates are stored as strings in ISO8601 format with a bit of extra "magic". I suspect that doesn't involve truncating time parts or rather, converting `.Date=.Date` to a range query. Change the condition to the equivalent `x.Date >= date.Date && x.Date < date.Date.AddDays(1)`

Comment: Good to know your info. And fantastic solution you have provided. You could rewrite it as an answer. @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

> CosmosDB [doesn't have a DateTime type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/working-with-dates) and dates are stored as strings in ISO8601 format with a bit of extra "magic". I suspect that doesn't involve truncating time parts or rather, converting `.Date=.Date` to a range query. Change the condition to the equivalent `x.Date >= date.Date && x.Date < date.Date.AddDays(1)`

As Panagiotis Kanavos said in comments, the recommended approach for querying dates in Cosmos DB is to use a range query. Below is the code which have used same approach to compare Date from `DateTime` using LINQ.

```cs
using (var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endpointUrl, primaryKey))
{
    var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(databaseId);

    var container = database.GetContainer(containerId);

    var ordersQuery = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Order>(allowSynchronousQueryExecution: true)
    .Where(x => x.ShipDate >= targetDate.Date && x.ShipDate < targetDate.Date.AddDays(1));

    var filteredOrders = ordersQuery.ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Filtered Orders:");
    foreach (var order in filteredOrders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Order ID: {order.OrderId}, Ship Date: {order.ShipDate}");
    }
}
```

It checks the date in between of prior and after dates instead of checking with single date and retrieve the matched date from the container. **targetDate** in the above code is to compare with the **ShipDate** stored in the cosmos db container. Below is the output after comparing Date from `DateTime` using LINQ.

Sample Input taken in my azure cosmos db container:

```js
[
    {
        "OrderId": 1,
        "ShipDate": "2024-01-18T10:30:00Z",
        "id": "c20dff36-2971-407e-a856-c8b9bd284626"
    },
    {
        "OrderId": 2,
        "ShipDate": "2024-01-21T15:45:00Z",
        "id": "452a9a12-5e94-4bec-a20d-e0447b2c2e90"
    },
    {
        "OrderId": 3,
        "ShipDate": "2024-01-19T08:00:00Z",
        "id": "1dea9ba8-c49b-486f-8dd8-bfe9bafddfff"
    }
]
```

**Output:**

```js
Filtered Orders:
Order ID: 2, Ship Date: 1/21/2024 3:45:00 PM
```